# Rails 4 - ajax:success isn't being triggered

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I submit a form via ajax. I can see in the network panel of Chrome that it was succesfful and returned some JSON. However, the "ajax:success" event is never being fired. Why?

```
// Does not work, despite getting success in the Network Panel.
$('#uploadDataForm').on("ajax:success", function(){
    console.log('file uploaded!');
});

// Works.
$('#uploadDataForm').on("ajax:send", function(){
    console.log('file sent!');
    console.log('yep');
});
```

Comment: You're using Rails `remote` functionality with the form?

Comment: Can you please put your controller code for this request

Answer (score 1):

if your using less than 1.7 Try

```
$("#uploadDataForm").bind("ajax:success", function() {
      console.log('file sent!');
    console.log('yep');
    });
```

Otherwise check you are getting a 200 response not 304 or something

or try using the global ajax response [ajax .ajaxSuccess()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", function() {
      console.log('file sent!');
    console.log('yep');
    });
```