# rails 4 ajax event not triggering success

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on my rails 4 demo app, and I've got a button that is meant to do some work on the server side, then return `json` with a success or failure message.

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918193/rails-4-ajaxsuccess-isnt-being-triggered) question, I am seeing the response come back with a 200 code and the expected `json` payload, but the jQuery success event is not triggered-- to make it more confusing, it seems to be somewhat intermittent-- sometimes I get the proper action (showing a flash message and removing a div) but most of the time nothing happens.

Here's the button in the view:

```
<%= link_to 'Do Work', widget_path(:id => widget.id), id: widget.id, remote: true, method: :get %>
```

Here's the controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if widget.save
    // this json is returned properly
    format.json { render json: { status: 'success', msg: 'Widget created.', :content_type => 'text/json', type: 'info', item: 'widget' } }
  else
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, :content_type => 'text/json', status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

The javascript in `application.js`:

```
var fade_flash = function() {
    $("#flash_success").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
    $("#flash_info").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
    $("#flash_warning").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
    $("#flash_danger").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
};
fade_flash();

var show_ajax_message = function(msg, type) {
    $("#notice").html('<div id="flash_'+type+'" class="alert alert-dismissable alert-'+type+'"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'+msg+'</div>');
    fade_flash();
};
```

Here's the coffeescript in `widget.js.coffee`:

```
$ ->
  $("a[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    alert('got here')
    console.dir(data)
    if data.status == 'success' 
        show_ajax_message(data.msg, data.type) 
        if data.item == 'widget'
            $('#widget_'+this.id).hide('slow')
```

Comment: I usually don't use these events so I'm not familiar with it.  What happens when you bind the event to `document` instead of the link (as stated in https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Turbolinks**

Your problem is likely to be an issue with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks):

> Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.
>   Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS
>   between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and
>   replaces only the body and the title in the head. Think CGI vs
>   persistent process

Turbolinks basically loads your pages with Ajax (leaving `<head>` tags in place), loading your pages faster... but also causing your JS to not fire

Issue being JS works by *binding* to DOM elements at load. If DOM elements are not present, they can't be bound, causing problem

---

**Fix**

The way you need to fix this is to use [javascript delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

This works by binding events to a "container" element (typically `document`) and *delegating* down to the sub elements. This works because `document` is always present, and consequently JS will always be able to fire whether the DOM elements are present at load or not:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var fade_flash = function() {
    $("#flash_success").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
    $("#flash_info").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
    $("#flash_warning").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
    $("#flash_danger").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
};

var show_ajax_message = function(msg, type) {
    $("#notice").html('<div id="flash_'+type+'" class="alert alert-dismissable alert-'+type+'"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'+msg+'</div>');
    fade_flash();
};

$(document).on("read page:load", fade_flash);

#app/assets/javascripts/widgets.js.coffee
$ ->
  $(document).on "ajax:success", "a[data-remote]", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    // meaningless comment to get past edit limit-- added comma in line above
    alert('got here')
    console.dir(data)
    if data.status == 'success' 
        show_ajax_message(data.msg, data.type) 
        if data.item == 'widget'
            $('#widget_'+this.id).hide('slow')
```